# Remove only the first occurrence of an item from a list in elm

Tags: list, algorithm, functional-programming, elm

Let's say I have a list of characters

```
letters = ['B','A', 'M', 'B', 'A']
```

I want a function that will remove the first instance a given character

```
removeSingleItem letters 'A'
-- ['B','M', 'B', 'A']
```

I can do this using recursion

```
removeSingleItem list item new =
    case list of
        [] -> new
        (x::xs) -> 
            if x == item then
                new ++ xs
             else 
                removeSingleItem xs item (new ++ [x])
```

But I feel this is a verbose solution, but I cannot see a way to do this with `List.filter` without removing all the matching items.

Is there a simpler way to do this using core `List` operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bigger problem with your code is that it is very inefficient because it keeps unnecessarily concatenating and creating new lists. It's possible to make it both much more efficient, simpler and slightly less verbose as a recursive function:

```
removeSingleItem list item =
    case list of
        [] -> []
        x :: xs ->
            if x == item then
                xs
            else
                x :: removeSingleItem xs item
```

Although do note that this is not tail recursive, so it will not work on large lists, but I don't see that being mentioned as a requirement. It is of course possible to make it tail recursive as well, while still being much more efficient, but at the cost of some additional complexity.

You could also do it using a fold (such as `List.foldl`), but that definitely wouldn't be simpler, or less verbose.

And if you don't mind taking on a dependency, this funcction already exists in [`list-extra`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest) as [`List.Extra.remove`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#remove) (which is tail recursive).

Comment: `List.Extra.remove` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @glennsl

Comment: Why is this function not tail recursive? And how would one make it tail recursive?

Comment: Just because it would be slightly more complicated, and simplicity seemed to be the focus here. Essentially you'd just need to add an accumulator argument and reverse the accumulated result at the end. You can see how `List.Extra.remove` is implemented here: https://github.com/elm-community/list-extra/blob/22cb6ea5a435c468654f5b7f6664f050c28ba365/src/List/Extra.elm#L851-L869